# Keep X amount of files in folder, forfiles

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I would like to keep the X latest files from a folder and delete the rest. Is this possible with `FORFILES`? If it's not I can fallback to another solution I seen here. Thanks for help.

I did this but it takes by dates: **EDIT**

```
forfiles /p [path] /s /d -5 /c "cmd /c echo @file"
```

(echo file for testing purpose)

Comment: `/d +5` does not make sense as this means "files that will be modified in 5 or more days" (that's the way `forfiles` interpretes that stupidly; I think you want files that are 5 days old or newer)

Comment: @aschipfl was a "typo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET /a retain=10

FOR /f "skip=%retain%delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /o-d "%targetdir%\*" '
 ) DO ECHO (DEL "%targetdir%\%%a"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances. Equally, this procedure targets all files - change the filemask to suit.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

method is to simply execute a `dir` in basic form without directories, sorted in reverse-date order.

Skip the first 10 entries, and delete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

With `forfiles` I see no chance to accomplish your task of returning the newest (most recent) number of files.

So my idea for this approach is this:

- to use `dir /B /A:-D /T:C /O:-D` to retrieve a bare list (`/B`) of files (no directories, `/A:-D`), sorted by creation date (`/T:C`; if you want to use the last modification date, simply remove the `/T:C` portion) in decending order (`/O:-D`), meaning newest items first;
- to put over a `for /F "eol=| delims="` loop to gather and parse the `dir` output line by line, meaning file by file, not excluding file names beginning with `;` (`eol=|`, `|` is illegal for file names) and not splitting file names containing white-spaces like <kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd> (`delims=`);
- to establish a variable that constitutes a counter, incremented per each loop iteration;
- to place an `if` condition inside of the loop to check if the counter reached the desired limit number and in case it is fulfilled, to break the `for /F` loop by `goto`;

Here is the related code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define global constants here:
set "TARGETPATH=\path\to\files\*.*"
set /A "TOTAL=10"

set /A "COUNT=0"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /T:C /O:-D "%TARGETPATH%"
') do (
    echo(%%F
    set /A COUNT+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if !COUNT! GEQ %TOTAL% (
        endlocal
        goto :NEXT
    ) else (
        endlocal
    )
)
:NEXT
endlocal
exit /B
```

I toggled the [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) within the `for /F` loop to avoid trouble in case file names contain exclamation marks `!`, which would get lost in the line `echo(%%F` in case it is on.

---

#### Update

The following code accomplishes the original task of your question, namely to delete files in a given directory but to keep the most recent number of files:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define global constants here:
set "TARGETPATH=\path\to\files\*.*"
set /A "TOTAL=10"

set "SKIPOPT=" & if %TOTAL% GTR 0 set "SKIPOPT=skip=%TOTAL% "
for /F "%SKIPOPT%eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /T:C /O:-D "%TARGETPATH%"
') do (
    del /P "%%F"
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Since `for /F` supports a `skip=` to skip the given number of lines, and so files in our situation, let us make use of it. It is given indirectly here via variable `SKIPOPT`, which holds the entire option string like `skip=10` (given that `TOTAL` is set to `10`). The `if %TOTAL% GTR 0` query is implemented for the script not to fail in case `TOTAL` is `0`, because `for /F` does not accept the option `skip=0`.

The `/P` switch at the `del` command lets appear a prompt `Delete (Y/N)?` for testing purposes. If you do not want any prompts, simply remove it.

Comment: Why not just use the DIR command you are using with the SKIP option in the FOR /F command?

Comment: Yes, of course, @Squashman, I was so focused on translating and extending the `forfiles` command line that I completely masked out the real question; I will update my answer accordingly...